# How to target Mac with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, macos, stylesheet

I need to use specific styles for Mac in my stylesheet. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why? (15 characters)

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted; whether or not it is a good idea isn't much reflection on the question, which despite leaving a lot to be desired ("best" should always be defined..) is as at least short and to the point.

Comment: After my earlier comment, I wrote an answer for the sake of answering the question, and it got instantly downvoted, so I deleted it.

Comment: i have differences in rendering styles (background-color in inline elements) on mac i have spaces between lines unlike in windows.
P.S. sorry for my english..

Comment: So you **don't** get the spaces in Firefox, Safari, Chrome or Opera on Windows but you **do** get the spaces in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera on Mac? Even if you load the file over HTTP (and not off the local file system)?

Comment: yes. over http. (but don't test it on opera in mac.)

Comment: @sarnold, on the same note, I wonder why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: Like @GromS I also see differences in how a very simple html/css page is rendered. All Win 8.1 FF, Chrome, IE10 show the same. However in OSX Chrome & Safari render the same but different to the Windows browsers. Strange, but true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or JavaScript

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Macintosh/))
    // do stuff for Macs here, such as load a stylesheet
```

But really, this is bad practice and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: why is this a bad practice? No explanation?

Answer (score 7):

In an ideal world you shouldn't need to fork styles for different os. However sometimes a specific design will require it - particularly with styling form elements.

If you really have to, the following script will set a class on the html element:

```
(function (flags, app) {
    os('Win', 'os-win');
    os('Mac', 'os-mac');

    if (document.documentElement) {
        document.documentElement.className += flags.join(' ');
    }

    function os (s, f) { if (app.indexOf(s) !== -1) flags.push(f); }

}([''], String(navigator && navigator.appVersion)));
```

You can execute this in the html head which means the page doesn't re-render after the initial loading.

You can then use mac specific css rules like so:

```
.os-mac #my-element { ... }
```

**Note: The best thing to do is find a solution that doesn't require forking for the OS.**

Answer (score 1):

The `navigator.platform` property returns `'MacIntel'` on OS X Safari, Chrome and Firefox (I don't have any PPC boxes at hand). If I would do it, I would check for that, and probably put in a class named `.mac` on the `<BODY>` tag and use that as a basis for the Mac-specific stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Only for mac:

```
 <script>(function(e,t){function n(n,r){if(t.indexOf(n)!==-1)e.push(r)}n("Mac","os-mac");if(document.documentElement){document.documentElement.className+=e.join(" ")}})([""],String(navigator&&navigator.appVersion))</script>
```

It works like johnhunter's solution, only that it is minified.